# Why does this injection of STDOUT through let cause a segmentation fault in ruby?

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, stdout

Full code example is at https://github.com/compwron/seg_replicator

ruby version `ruby-2.0.0-p353` (see .rvmrc in example)

Interestingly, if I use .ruby-version the segfault does not replicate (see commit 2, i.e. the diff at https://github.com/compwron/seg_replicator/commit/955ff64fb8a45ac12cc4361f99b581baaa60fa3e for the change that takes the sample code from hanging-forever to segfaulting)

```
    class Game
  def initialize(stdout = STDOUT)
    $stdout = stdout
  end

  def foo
    0
  end
end

require_relative '../lib/game'
describe Game do
  let(:output) do
    StringIO.new
    $stdout = output
  end
  let(:g) { Game.new output }

  describe 'foo' do
    it 'test 1' do
      expect(g.foo).to eq 0
    end

    it 'test 2' do
      expect(g.foo).to eq 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have a solution for how to inject stdout that I am happy with; I am just curious about how this code causes a segfault rather than just throwing an error of some sort

Comment: Obviously, this should either run into an infinite loop or a `SystemStackError`, the segfault is clearly a bug which you should report.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But there are so many steps and it might exist already but I can't find it, and it might be an interaction with rspec version? https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/HowToReport (rspec 3.0.0 in Gemfile.lock)